# Report to show duplicate cases created in 48 hours

Tags: custom-reports, inner-join

I want to create a reports to show only duplicate cases (With same type and sub type) which is created within 48 hrs

Comment: You can write queries like this, but not reports. Ultimately, this means you'd have to write some code to display this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is the following:

1. Create another field on Case (checkbox) `Is_Duplicate__c`
2. Using either a before Apex trigger or Visual Flow trigged by Process Builder, when a case is created or updated, set the checkbox field to true if any other Case matches on type+subtype. You may find creating a composite field (type+subtype) helps in the searching.

Then you can write a report that looks for `Is_Duplicate__c` = true and `CreatedDate` = Last 2 Days